# setting up enum in a singleton within an ios app such that it can be accessed throughout the app

Tags: ios, enums, singleton, global-variables

I would like to set up my global constant values within a Constants Singleton class in my iOS app such that any class importing the constants can use those values.

However, after playing around for a few hours with this idea, I am still unable to make it work.

In my Constants.m file

```
 @interface Constants()
 {
    @private
    int _NumBackgroundNetworkTasks;
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter;
 }
 @end

 @implementation Constants

 static Constants *constantSingleton = nil;
 //Categories of entries
 typedef enum
 {
   mapViewAccessoryButton = 999

  } UIBUTTON_TAG;


 +(id)getSingleton
 {

   .....
  }
```

I have another class MapViewController where I have a reference to the Constants singleton and Im trying to access the enums like this

```
 myDetailButton.tag =  self.constSingleton.UIBUTTON_TAG.mapViewAccessoryButton;
```

However, this is not working. Im not able to access the UIBUTTON_TAG inside the mapviewcontroller

ANybody have any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the enum available throughout the app, put the enum definition in the .h file, not the .m file.

**Update**:

Objective-C doesn't support namespaces and it doesn't support class level constants or enums.

The line:

```
myDetailButton.tag =  self.constSingleton.UIBUTTON_TAG.mapViewAccessoryButton;
```

should be:

```
myDetailButton.tag =  mapViewAccessoryButton;
```

assuming you define the `UIBUTTON_TAG` enum in some .h file.

When you compile an Objective-C app, all values of all enum must have unique names. This is a result of Objetive-C being based on C.

**Update 2**:

There is one way to get what you want but not with enums. Something like this should work:

Constants.h:

```
@interface UIBUTTON_TAG_ENUM : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) int mapViewAccessoryButton;
// define any other "enum values" as additional properties

@end

@interface Constants : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, readonly) UIBUTTON_TAG_ENUM *UIBUTTON_TAG;

+ (id)getSingleton;

// anything else you want in Constants

@end
```

Constants.m

```
@implementation UIBUTTON_TAG_ENUM

- (int)mapViewAccessoryButton {
    return 999;
}

@end

@implementation Constants {
    int _NumBackgroundNetworkTasks;
    NSDateFormatter *_formatter;
    UIBUTTON_TAG_ENUM *_uiButtonTag;
}

@synthesize UIBUTTON_TAG = _uiButtonTag;

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _uiButtonTag = [[UIBUTTON_TAG_ENUM alloc] init];
    }

    return self;
}

// all of your other code for Constants

@end
```

Now you can do:

```
myDetailButton.tag =  self.constSingleton.UIBUTTON_TAG.mapViewAccessoryButton;
```

I'm not sure if there is a point to this though.

Comment: It works if I put it in the .h file but I would prefer the variable encapsulated in the Constants class. Im having a hard time configuring that. Seems simple but for some reason I cant make it work

Comment: @banditKing you can't simultaneously have the enum visible to other classes and hide its existence from them...

Comment: can I encapsulate the enum in Constants and then access it through Constants properties only? Thats what I want to do but dont know how

Comment: Thanks. +1 for the detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is simply stick it in your precompiled header (.pch) if you aren't going to be changing the enum a lot.